# Best way of creating routing system using pushState api and routing system of other frameworks and library

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, vue.js

I am from Angular.js background now I am using Vue.js and React.js , I am very interested in SPA , Now I am trying to my own js framework for SPA , when it comes to routing system I observed routing system of Angular.js ,vue.js and react.js . After observation I got to know that Angular.js sends ajax request each and every time to load templates where as vue.js and react.js doesn't send request because it consider component's as SPA templates.

**My Question:**

Now I want to know which is better way sending ajax request or using components as SPA templates ?

How can I make best routing system using push state api ?

I am looking for Based on performance (Speed)